# Problems with the main rotor speed in Airbus H175 (42145) set?

Tags: technic, electronics, powered-up

I'm having problems with the main rotor in "slow" position. The speed stays the same no matter what position the joystick is in. On the other hand, in "fast" position the blades slow down When the joystick is in the forward position but works fine with left, right and backward. Does anyone know a fix?